# sveltefire : how to chain firestore where queries in svelte with sveltefire

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, svelte

How do I chain where queries in sveltefire?

chaining other queries is working. but not where queries. such as:

```js
query={(ref) => ref.where("timestamp", ">", 1622458092).limit(10)}
```

but when chaninig two where queries, results dont load anymore. eg.

```js
query={(ref) => ref.where("timestamp", ">", 1622458092).where("refId","==","101")}
```

*both queries work separately. but not together. (and common results exists).*
how would one fix that.

Answer (score 0):

To combine multiple where clause you need to use Firestore's [Composite Index](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/indexing#create_a_composite_index)